# Angular 5 & 6 *ngFor last nth element of observable<any[]>

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

Hello I am developing a web app using Angular 6.

My web app is linked to a firebase database, from where I get a list of objects.
On my landing page I want to display the last 6 objects in that list.
I got it to work with the first 6 using pipes, but I cannot figure out a solution to get the last 6.

```html
<ul>
  <div *ngFor="let course of coursesObservable | async | slice:0:6">
      <ngb-alert type="info" [dismissible]="false">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img src="{{course.file}}">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <h3><a href="#">{{course.name}}</a> </h3>
                </div>
          </div>
      </ngb-alert> 
  </div>
</ul>
```

The above HTML snippet shows how I got it to work with the first 6 elements.
I have tried to do the following:

```html
  <div *ngFor="let course of (coursesObservable | async | slice:coursesObservable.length-6:coursesObservable.length-1);">
```

But nothing happens. I get no error messages in my Chrome console either. The result is that no events are displayed at all.

I have also tried to keep track of the index and only generate my tags when the index is equal to or greater than the length of the list - 6. So if the length is 50, then only generate when 44+.

```html
  <div *ngFor="let course of coursesObservable | async | let i=index;">
      <ngb-alert *ngIf="i >= coursesObservable.length-6" type="info" [dismissible]="false">
```

This generates an error in my console.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token = at column 48 in [let course of 
coursesObservable | async | let i=index;] in 
ng:///AppModule/DummyListComponent.html@1:7 ("<ul>
<div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let course of coursesObservable | async | let 
i=index;">
<ngb-alert *ngIf="i >= courses"): 
ng:///AppModule/DummyListComponent.html@1:7
The pipe 'let' could not be found ("<ul>
```

I have considered doing the slicing in my TypeScript file for the component displaying this list of alerts tags. I do not know how to splice an array of observable or how to convert it to an array. If this is a good approach, perhaps I need help in this file instead.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// Firebase
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'dummy-list',
  templateUrl: './dummy-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dummy-list.component.css']
})
export class DummyListComponent implements OnInit {
  coursesObservable: Observable<any[]>;
  events: any[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coursesObservable = this.getDummy('/events');
  }

  getDummy(listPath): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.db.list(listPath).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence. `slice(-2)` extracts the last two elements in the sequence.

So just use `slice:-6`.

Comment: That'll work. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I hope it is helpful to someone else as well. Cheers.